# Interchanging limits with the prime counting function

Tags: limits, prime-numbers, asymptotics, probability-limit-theorems

How does one justify that
$$\lim_{s \to 1} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{x^s} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{s \to 1} \frac{\pi(x)}{x^s}, \quad s > 1,$$
without using the fact that the primes have density zero, i.e., $\lim_{x \to \infty} = \pi(x)/x = 0$, and the prime number theorem.

Comment: What's the context here? Since $\pi(x)/x^s \sim x^{1-s} /\log x$ as $x\to\infty$, the inner limit on the left is $0$ if $s \leq 1$ and $\infty$ is $s > 1$.

Comment: @anomaly How is the limit on the left $\infty$ if $s > 1$? Note that $0 \leq \pi(x) x^{-s} \leq x^{1 - s}$ whenever $s > 1$.

Comment: Yes, that should be $0$ if $s\geq 1$ and $\infty$ if $s < 1$.